# Setting tag number according to sections

Tags: equations, numbering

**Question:**

> How does one set the tags numbering according to the related section or subsection? E.g. If it is the section 3.4 I would like to be able to label an equation as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\begin{document} $$(s_1 \circ \varphi^{-1}_1)^*\boldsymbol \omega =\mathrm{Im} \left(\frac{\bar q}{1+|q|^2}dq\right) \tag{3.4.1} $$
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to do so yet, and I would like to know if it is possible. If so, could anyone show how?

Comment: if you're using `amsmath`, you can get this numbering automatically if you use the `equation` environment and set the equation counter using `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` or `...{...}{subsection}`.

Comment: @Werner I know how to number for figures. I just don't know how tu use the same numbering with tags.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: The question covers "other document elements", including that of `equation`s.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which elements you have, so with some redundantion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}

\begin{document} 

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesubsection.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\section{Three}
\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\subsection{Four}
%$$
\begin{equation}
(s_1 \circ \varphi^{-1}_1)^*\boldsymbol \omega =\mathrm{Im} \left(\frac{\bar q}{1+|q|^2}dq\right) 
%\tag{3.4.1} $$
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used \begin {equation}\end{equation} but it doesn't who like yours, just (1).

Comment: @AaronMaroja The crucial is `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesubsection.\arabic{equation}}`.

Comment: I used \numberwithin{equation}{section} and it worked.